# Android APK size big - how to keep autoupdate size small?

Tags: java, android, size, apk, auto-update

The android app I am currently writing for my company requires an autoupdate feature that can also be used over the cellular network. So the APK must be as small as possible to ensure small update sizes. Currently my app is 10MB in size and that is too much according to the company. I cannot strip any libraries from the project. Unfortunately my app uses severial library that I fear makes up most of the APK size. I suggested only allowing WLAN updates but unfortunately the company does not agree.

Questions:
1. Is there not the possibility to transfer only patches as an update to an existing APK, or must the whole APK always be replaced? I mean patches are kind of common on the PC side.
2. can I not externalize libraries instead of including them in the APK, so that the update only includes non-library stuff?

Note: the app will NOT be available in the play store, so a custom update mechanism will need to be written.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

EDIT:

Using

```
actionbarsherlock
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\httpclient-4.2.1.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\httpcore-4.2.1.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\httpmime-4.2.1.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\joda-time-2.1.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\joda-time-2.1.jar.properties"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\mail.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\ormlite-android-4.42.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\ormlite-android-4.42.jar.properties"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\ormlite-core-4.42.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\ormlite-core-4.42.jar.properties"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\reflections-0.9.5.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\reflections-0.9.5-javadoc.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\reflections-0.9.5-sources.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\saripaar-11242012.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\activation.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\additionnal.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\commons-lang3-3.1.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\gson-2.2.2.jar"
"C:\Users\alex\workspace\mobile_service\libs\guava-14.0-rc1.jar"
```

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: Could you give us that same break down of those libraries based and sorted on their file size?

Comment: Main thing is that What is there in auto update data?

Comment: ActionBarSherlock is pretty sizable already. One alternative would be break down your apk into multiple versions, with the later versions needing less space, and the average updates taking less bandwidth. Using a different approach, perhaps you could even break down your apk into two apks for the same device, one that would be updated often, and one apk that would be updated rarely if ever.

Comment: Another problem is that this limit imposed on you by this company seems completely arbitrary. What specific reasons are behind this limit?  If they can't give you actual reasons, it means you're just building your application on quick sand, and that tomorrow, they may just find some other completely different arbitrary reason that your app doesn't work for them.

Comment: The reason they mention it is because supposeadly not every place in the world has wireless LAN. So I should give up whole features/libraries of the program to satisfy a fraction of the customers? Yeah that argument makes no sense but at the end of the day I cannot refuse work if my superiors still tell me to do it. I am also an apprentice and there are people with "experience" telling me what to do. If our customers ask us to jump out of the window we would gladly to it. For money, though that metaphor tell alot about the consequences. LOL

Comment: Typically static images and raw assets take up the most space. You could look into removing ldpi/mdpi resources to gain some space (if you have them).

Comment: What are you updating? You can save "updatable stuff" to the sdcard and then download the new updates and replace the old ones. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish specifically.

Comment: I'm sure you could get rid of the javadocs and sources that you listed in libs.